# Cannot publish Website with web reference - SGEN error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, publish, web-reference, sgen

I have website (MVC) with one Web reference. Build and run in VS working. But when I tried to publish to disk I get error:

SGEN: error: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

If I remove web reference then publishing working. Where can be a problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found solutions. I am using Visual Studio 2013. I update to update version 4. After that, publish working perfectly.

Comment: Another solutions:
Disable generate serialization assembly in project properties in build tab.